# My gdb generate different core file when I attach to a process(64-bit and 32-bit)

Tags: linux, gdb, core-file

I have a file 'manager_server.ex'

```bash
$ file manager_server.ex
manager_server.ex: ELF 32-bit LSB  executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (GNU/Linux), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, BuildID[sha1]=709713ebf61f867e84d1d2818baea02b562c7ee7, not stripped
```

**I ran this file and then deleted it**. Now I try generate a core file by gdb(generate-core-file),but I get different core file(64-bit and 32-bit).
This is a correct core file：

```bash
$ sudo gdb manager_server.ex -p 28108
(gdb) generate-core-file
(gdb) quit
$ file core.28108
core.28108: ELF 32-bit LSB  core file Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), SVR4-style, from '/home/ubuntu/sstx10006/manager_server'
```

those are not:

```bash
$ sudo gdb
(gdb) set archi i386
(gdb) attach 28108
(gdb) generate-core-file
(gdb) quit
$ file core.28108
core.28108: ELF 64-bit LSB  core file x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), SVR4-style, from '/sstx10006/manager_server'
```

```bash
$ sudo gdb
(gdb) set archi i386:x86-64
(gdb) attach 28108
(gdb) generate-core-file
(gdb) quit
$ file core.28108
core.28108: ELF 64-bit LSB  core file x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), SVR4-style, from '/home/ubuntu/sstx10006/manager_server'
```

```bash
$ sudo gdb
(gdb) attach 28108
(gdb) generate-core-file
(gdb) quit
$ file core.28108
core.28108: ELF 64-bit LSB  core file x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), SVR4-style, from '/sstx10006/manager_server'
```

I want to know what make them different. I asked ChatGPT, but the explanation it provided was incorrect.

Comment: no, it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to know what make them different.

It looks that when the executable is *not* deleted, both `gdb -p $pid` and `(gdb) attach $pid` read the `/proc/$pid/exe` symlink and use that executable. But when the file is deleted, GDB fails to load the `manager_server.ex (deleted)`.

1. This looks like a bug in GDB: it could use `/proc/$pid/exe` directly instead of dereferencing it.
2. GDB *warns* about "not understanding what's going on":

```
(gdb) attach 2655529
Attaching to process 2655529
No executable file now.
warning: Could not load vsyscall page because no executable was specified
```

3. The following works correctly:

```
gdb /proc/2655529/exe
attach 2655529
(gdb) gcore
```